Who is interested in competing (underhanded crypto)?
I came across the Underhanded Crypto Contest recently. Anyone on here interested in forming a team and putting together a submission?
The idea is to design a cryptosystem or modify an existing one, in such a way that the code looks fine but has a subtle flaw that should escape expert detection.
The submission deadline is 02 December 2014.
If we get a few people interested (just leave me a comment here or in chat), I'll create a chat-room and invite those who respond. We can use that to discuss ideas and plan our submission.
Any level of participation would be great. Even if all you can do is pop in on chat and critique our ideas, that would be very welcome. We will need people who can help implement the idea though too.
I see this as a great way to promote the site and our community.

Damn, wish I had seen the competition last week, I might have tried to make it into a thesis topic somehow... I'm still interested, could help at least with critique and code review.

I'd be interested, but with my lack of serious crypto expertise, I'm not sure I'd be of much help.

I created the Underhanded room and invited those who have responded. If anyone else is interested, feel free to comment here or message me on chat. I'll add you to the room. And FYI, no strings attached. If you end up not being able to help beyond critiquing ideas, that is fine.

I made a request to enter the private room!

@curious Thanks for letting me know. For some reason I don't get a notification when someone requests access.

It's not specifically about cryptography, but let me note that the Underhanded C contest is open as well: http://www.underhanded-c.org/

So I entered this (gotta get the underhanded dual trophy after winning the C one) but have not heard a thing other than that I made it to the final round. Was the contest canceled?

@JohnMeacham we ended up not putting together a submission, but I had hoped to see the entries for next year (assuming they do it again). Haven't seen anything either.

Hey, what do you know.
https://underhandedcrypto.com/2015/03/07/announcing-the-underhanded-champs/ :)

@john congrats. I haven't read the whole thing, but will eventually.
